# When I selected a word, and typing, The character typed append in first of the word

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

I use `Windows 7` and `MS Word 2010`.
When I selected a word, and typing, The character typed append in first of the word, and don't overwrite on the selected word. How can I fix it?

Fore example, If I have this:
`Hello Nabi`

If I select `Nabi`, Now I type `a` character. Must be have this:
`Hello a`

But I see this:
`Hello aNabi`

How can fix this?

Comment: This is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer.
`File > Options > Advance` and check `Typing replaces selected text`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LukePeterson I don't know as you said. But I know this is exactly my answer!